# Why GetType() is not able to identify this type?

Tags: c#, types

Here's the [code](http://rextester.com/YVHG82549):

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
       Test test = new Test();
    }
}

public class Test
{
    public Test() {
        Console.WriteLine("type: " + Type.GetType("Registration"));        
    }
}

public class Registration
{
    public int mAge;
    public string mName;

    public Registration() {}
}
```

When it try to get the type for `Registration`, it returns null. So both `.Name` or `.AssemblyQualifiedName` can't be accessed.

I can provide `AssemblyQualifiedName` only if `GetType()` doesn't return `null`.

Why `GetType()` returns null? Hope the question is clear.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That works fine. If it doesn't work for you, then there's probably a *namespace*, in which case you need `"TheNamespace.Registration"`. If the type is in a different assembly, you'll need to specify *that too*; ultimately the most reliable string version is the type's `AssemblyQualifiedName` - which could be something like `"Registration, ConsoleApp48, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"`, or longer if there's a strong-name involved.

However, `typeof(Registration)` would be easier than *any* of these options.

Comment: Why it seems to don't work using different namespace? http://rextester.com/XSIKO23415

Comment: @markzzz the fully qualified name of that (not including the assembly part) is `WebApi.WebAPIController+Registration` (note the `+`, not `.`)

Comment: Oh... that's `+`. Why `+` here and not `.`?

Comment: @markzzz because `Type.GetType()` needs to work the same for any caller language, so it uses the CLR's type name conventions, which do not match C#'s type name conventions. In C# a nested type is `Outer.Inner`. In CLR terms, a nested type is `Outer+Inner`

Comment: @markzzz similarly, in C# a `List<T>` is: `List<T>`. To the CLR that is `List\`1[[T]]`. As for why, consider: in VB it is `List(Of T)`; in F# it is ... I don't even know what

Comment: Thanks dude, clear! +1

Answer (score 4):

You need to specifiy the "assembly qualified" type name:

```
Type.GetType("YourNameSpace.Registration");
```

As the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.gettype?view=netframework-4.8#System_Type_GetType_System_String_) states:

> typeName
>      Type: System.String
>
> The assembly-qualified name of the type to get. See
>     AssemblyQualifiedName. If the type is in the currently
>     executing assembly or in Mscorlib.dll, it is sufficient to supply the
>   type name qualified by its namespace.

Answer (score 3):

You need to specify the full name of the type, including the namespace:

```
Console.WriteLine("type: " + Type.GetType("Rextester.Registration"));
```

Or alternatively - depending on what you're trying to do:

```
Console.WriteLine("type: " + typeof(Registration));
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to define the full namespace path to your class, so something like `TestNamespace.Registration`